# How to make post templates to include shortcodes only?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, shortcode

I used to post same shortcodes every time (shortcodes loads dynamic contents). So, I want to pack these shortcodes in a template for my posts. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out...
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

But the gist for using shortcodes in a template is as follows...

`// Use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor).
do_shortcode('[gallery]');`